Sorting numbers within a cell without omitting the 0
I would like to sort numbers from smallest to largest within a single cell. The current cell content is 1, 4, 0, 2, -9, -10 and should be -10, -9, 0, 1, 2, 4
I managed to sort it, however, the 0 is omitted in the output which is an issue. How can I make sure the entire content is sorted?
For reference, this is the current formula I am using:
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFERROR(1/(1/SMALL(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A5,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),ROW($1:$99))),""))


0 is omitted because 1/(1/small results in #DIV/0! and thus replaced with blank. It doesn't look like that double division is needed here anyway, so omitting it will include 0 and get the expected result.

You could try using the TEXTSPLIT() function here:


• Formula used in cell B1
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,SORT(--TEXTSPLIT(A1,,", ")))


• Or,
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFERROR(SMALL(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"),ROW(1:99)),""))


• If you have access to LET() then and not TEXTSPLIT():
=LET(
     a, 1/(1/SMALL(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"),ROW(1:99))),
     TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFERROR(IFNA(IF(ERROR.TYPE(a)=2,0,a),a),"")))


• Or,
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(1/(1/SMALL(--(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")&".1"),ROW($1:$99))),""),".1",))



Used your first suggestion and it worked perfectly, thank you SO much!
